# Pygame, font.render error

Tags: python

I am making game with pygame and am trying to print the variable "money" but whenever I try the game give me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\camil\Desktop\final\New.py", line 201, in <module>
    scoretext=font.render( money, 'coins', 1,(0,0,1))
TypeError: an integer is required
```

This is my code, I have no idea what the problem is so help would be much appreciated:

```
while True:
    global money

    plot = plot+1

    setDisplay.fill((255,255,255))

    font=pygame.font.Font(None,20)
    scoretext=font.render( money, 'coins', 1,(0,0,0))
    setDisplay.blit(scoretext, (1130, 5))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are trying to render the number of coins someone has - e.g. "10 coins"?

That being the case, you are passing the "10" and the "coins" as separate variables, and need to combine them into a single object before passing them to the function:

```
font.render('%d coins' % (money,), 1,(0,0,0))
```

Make sure you carefully look at the required parameters in the documentation:

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render

Answer (score 0):

The function prototype for Font.render() looks like this

```
Font.render(text, antialias, color, background=None): return Surface
```

You are not passing the correct arguments to the function, which is what the error message is telling you (an integer is required). I assume you want to display 'XXX coins', try this:

```
Font.render(money + ' coins', 0, 1, (0,0,0))
```